# Site.css is not refreshed in Firefox 35.0.1

Tags: css, firefox

I am testing MVC application in my default browser Firefox 35.0.1. I noticed the new CSS style I added is not working:

```
.mym1 {
    border: 5px double;
}
```

After extensive testing, closing, opening and cursing application I looked on **Site.css** as shown on the Firefox - the **.mym1** class was missing.
I changed my testing browser to Chrome - the class **.mym1** was shown in Site.css and the style worked. So I reverted testing back to Firefox - it shown the old **Site.css** missing the class **.mym1** and of course it did not work.

It is a Firefox bug or I need to change my configuration/setup?

Comment: clear browser cache, static files are often cached to improve performance.

Comment: A page refresh using `[ctrl]+[f5]` should usually take care of that.

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox, you can press ctrl + shift + del and choose to clear the cache. The style sheet was probably cached, so clearing the cache should solve the issue.